# Joining to Queries side by side calculating sales values by year

Tags: sql-server

I want to join 2 tables from 2 different queries side by side.

Q1= Employees sales value for one year

Q2= Employees sales values for another year

Expected output:
Employee / TotalSalesValue_1996 / TotalSalesValue_ 1997

Below is my unsuccessful attempt, it seams to duplicate the Value of Q2.

```
select A1.Employee, A1.Title, A1.TotalSalesValue_1996, A2.TotalSalesValue_1997 
from 
( 
  select concat(e.titleofcourtesy,' ', e.firstname, e.lastname) as Employee, e.Title, sum((od.unitprice * od.quantity) - (1 * od.discount)) as TotalSalesValue_1996
  from employees as e 
  inner join orders as o on o.employeeid=e.employeeid
  inner join order_details as od on od.orderid=o.orderid
  where o.ShippedDate between '1996-01-01' and '1996-12-31'
  group by e.title, concat(e.titleofcourtesy,' ', e.firstname, e.lastname)
) as A1
,
(
  select concat(e.titleofcourtesy,' ', e.firstname, e.lastname) as Employee, e.Title, sum((od.unitprice * od.quantity) - (1 * od.discount)) as TotalSalesValue_1997
  from employees as e 
  inner join orders as o on o.employeeid=e.employeeid
  inner join order_details as od on od.orderid=o.orderid
  where o.ShippedDate between '1997-01-01' and '1997-12-31'
  group by e.title, concat(e.titleofcourtesy,' ', e.firstname, e.lastname)
) as A2;
```

*Please note that I used one of the free data bases available (northwind.sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a JOIN clause. So instead of the comma betwee the tables, put `FULL OUTER JOIN`. And then after `A2` put `ON A1.Employee = A2.Employee AND A1.Title = A2.Title`.

But a better option might be to use a single query, with:

```
select 
   concat(e.titleofcourtesy,' ', e.firstname, e.lastname) as Employee, 
   e.Title, 
   sum(CASE WHEN o.ShippedDate between '1996-01-01' and '1996-12-31' THEN (od.unitprice * od.quantity) - (1 * od.discount) ELSE 0 END) as TotalSalesValue_1996, 
   sum(CASE WHEN o.ShippedDate between '1997-01-01' and '1997-12-31' THEN (od.unitprice * od.quantity) - (1 * od.discount) ELSE 0 END) as TotalSalesValue_1997
from employees as e 
inner join orders as o on o.employeeid=e.employeeid
inner join order_details as od on od.orderid=o.orderid
where o.ShippedDate between '1996-01-01' and '1996-12-31'
group by e.title, concat(e.titleofcourtesy,' ', e.firstname, e.lastname);
```

Comment: Thank you Rob, both of them work perfectly and your suggestion is much shorter and simpler.